# android:src attrs for custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, android-attributes

Is there a way to set default android attrs to the custom view, that would be available when defining this view in `xml`?. For example, I need to create `CustomImageView` that will be `FrameLayout` with `ImageView` and `ProgressBar` inside it. If I add such view in xml I want to set background or src of that view, for example. `FrameLayout` has no `android:src` attribute and it doesn't offer via Android Studio autocomplete window, can I make somehow Android Studio to know that this layout can process such attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to put `android:src` in custom styleables, located at `values/attrs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyView">
        <attr name="android:src"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And having `MyView` class that is a descendant of a `View`, then in `xml` file we'd see this:

[image]